# How to convert Apache Derby database to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, derby, data-conversion

I would like to convert an existing Derby database to MySQL.

Comment: What have you already tried? What problems have you encountered? Stack Overflow is not here to do it for you.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [DBCopy Plugin for SQuirreL SQL Client](http://dbcopyplugin.sourceforge.net/) if you only need to convert the database once. There are other tools that may work. I you need to convert regularly, then I would use CSV export / import (for the data).